# jade nested looping mysql array

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, web, express

Having an issue with jade and loop threw an array from a mysql query.  when I `console.log` a row I'm trying to log it dumps out this.

```
{ id: 512,
  first: 'Mark',
  last: 'Neal',
  client: 'City of South Bend',
  employer: null,
  access: null }
```

Which is fine.

Now I'm trying to set it up so jade will automatically fill in the column names and and the columns.  Anyway here's my jade code.

```
block content
  .container
  h1 Data Tables      
  .span12
    table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-condensed
      thead
        each f in fields
          th= f.name
      tbody
        each i in results
          tr
            each b in i
              td= b
```

Apparently I can't post pics because of this being my first post so I'll try copy and paste as best I can.

Instead of stopping at `}` it goes on like this in two new columns.

[image]

```
function (parser, fieldPackets, typeCast, nestTables, connection) {
  var self = this;
  var next = function () {
    return self._typeCast(fieldPacket, parser, connection.config.timezone, connection.config.supportBigNumbers, connection.config.bigNumberStrings);
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < fieldPackets.length; i++) {
    var fieldPacket = fieldPackets[i];
    var value;
    if (typeof typeCast == "function") {
      value = typeCast.apply(connection, [new Field({
        packet: fieldPacket,
        parser: parser
      }), next]);
    } else {
      value = (typeCast) ? this._typeCast(fieldPacket, parser, connection.config.timezone, connection.config.supportBigNumbers, connection.config.bigNumberStrings) : ((fieldPacket.charsetNr === Charsets.BINARY) ? parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer() : parser.parseLengthCodedString());
    } if (typeof nestTables == "string" && nestTables.length) {
      this[fieldPacket.table + nestTables + fieldPacket.name] = value;
    } else if (nestTables) {
      this[fieldPacket.table] = this[fieldPacket.table] || {};
      this[fieldPacket.table][fieldPacket.name] = value;
    } else {
      this[fieldPacket.name] = value;
    }
  }
}

function (field, parser, timeZone, supportBigNumbers, bigNumberStrings) {
  var numberString;
  switch (field.type) {
  case Types.TIMESTAMP:
  case Types.DATE:
  case Types.DATETIME:
  case Types.NEWDATE:
    var dateString = parser.parseLengthCodedString();
    var dt;
    if (dateString === null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (timeZone != 'local') {
      if (field.type === Types.DATE) {
        dateString += ' 00:00:00 ' + timeZone;
      } else {
        dateString += ' ' + timeZone;
      }
    }
    dt = new Date(dateString);
    if (isNaN(dt.getTime())) {
      return dateString;
    }
    return dt;
  case Types.TINY:
  case Types.SHORT:
  case Types.LONG:
  case Types.INT24:
  case Types.YEAR:
  case Types.FLOAT:
  case Types.DOUBLE:
    numberString = parser.parseLengthCodedString();
    return (numberString === null || (field.zeroFill && numberString[0] == "0")) ? numberString : Number(numberString);
  case Types.NEWDECIMAL:
  case Types.LONGLONG:
    numberString = parser.parseLengthCodedString();
    return (numberString === null || (field.zeroFill && numberString[0] == "0")) ? numberString : ((supportBigNumbers && (bigNumberStrings || (Number(numberString) > IEEE_754_BINARY_64_PRECISION))) ? numberString : Number(numberString));
  case Types.BIT:
    return parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer();
  case Types.STRING:
  case Types.VAR_STRING:
  case Types.TINY_BLOB:
  case Types.MEDIUM_BLOB:
  case Types.LONG_BLOB:
  case Types.BLOB:
    return (field.charsetNr === Charsets.BINARY) ? parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer() : parser.parseLengthCodedString();
  case Types.GEOMETRY:
    return parser.parseGeometryValue();
  default:
    return parser.parseLengthCodedString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are just looking at the JADE-code then this could be of help.
I Solved a similar progrem like this:

```
- each value, i in results
    tr
    - var count = 0
        - each b in i
            - if(count < Object.keys(value).length)
                td= b
            - count += 1
```

I changed the name of my own variables so it could fit in your JADE file.

Hopefully the code example is pretty self explanatory, but to explain how it works in short:

First of the variable "value" will get each item in the array "results", even if this is a JSON object with only different key values.

Afterwards I made a variable which counts the amount of keys. If you don't have the check against Object.keys(element).length) then it will print 2 more values which is the "parse" value and "_typeCast" values.

Anyways this count variable just counts the number of used keys which later compares to the number of total of keys in the JSON array, when all keys are printed then it wont print anymore.

Hopefully this will help you (or someone else!)